# Select name from SQL column

Tags: sql

I am trying to select the names (along with the rest of the information on the table such as data, time, lesson) of each user that is inside a users table. The names I'm trying to select are the ones that are on the same row as a particular teacherID. However when I run this code I'm getting the same name for all records, when I should be getting two different ones.

```
SELECT FName, SName, bookedLessons.bookedHour, 
       bookedLessons.bookedDate, bookedLessons.lesson 
FROM users JOIN bookedLessons 
WHERE  teacherID = 11 
  AND users.userID = (SELECT userID FROM bookedLessons WHERE teacherID = 11)
```

[image: The bookedLessons table I'm using]

[image: The users table I'm using]

[image: The results I'm getting]

Comment: UPDATE: after adding a bookedLessons.userID into the first select, I noticed I'm getting the right userID, but not the name

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join needs an `ON` clause but not the subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT u.FName, u.SName, b.bookedHour, b.bookedDate, b.lesson  
FROM bookedLessons b INNER JOIN users u 
ON u.userID = b.userID
WHERE b.teacherID = 11
```

Comment: Yeah that did it. I feel pretty dumb for not thinking about it! Thanks!